# Nested Loop inside a SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, string-aggregation

I have been trying to figure out if there is a way to have a Loop inside of a SQL Statement.

```
Select j.JobID, s.OrderNumber, 
(SELECT OperationID From Operations) as Operations  <--- This will cause multiple results
From Jobs j
Inner Join Sales s on j.JobID = s.SalesJobID
Where j.JobID = '123456-1-1'
```

this is what we have

```
JobID        OrderNumber    Operation
-----        -----------    ----------
1123456-1-1   TEST1         DEV
1123456-1-1   TEST1         APR
1123456-1-1   TEST1         CAT
1123456-1-1   TEST1         LFT
1123456-1-1   TEST1         PKG
```

Trying to do something like this.

```
JobID        OrderNumber    Operations
-----        -----------    ----------
1123456-1-1   TEST1         DEV, APR, CAT, LFT, PKG
```

Comment: Why loop???  SQL is a set based language.  You don't loop.  Try to look up `STRING_AGG()` if you are using SQL Server.  Otherwise tag your question properly with appropriate tag.

Comment: Also there are tons of example about this on the web.  Have you done any research at all???

Comment: @Eric yes I have.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, some of it depends on the database engine you are using (you didn't specify). You could do with a CTE, CURSOR, FOR XML PATH.

See this article for may ways of accomplishing your goal. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Comment: @mrmcg If you had, you wouldn't have needed to ask this question.  There are more than enough examples in the web.  I don't even see your attempt to get the query you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with XML PATH

```
Select j.JobID, s.OrderNumber, 
(SELECT OperationID + ',' From Operations WHERE add_your_filter_here FOR XML PATH ('')) as Operations
From Jobs j
Inner Join Sales s on j.JobID = s.SalesJobID
Where j.JobID = '123456-1-1'
```

Comment: I will check this out. Thanks.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you so very much